# Can't link dynamic library when running C language with root privileges?

Tags: c, linux, root, lib

I have a C language file named `testFunc.c` that uses the dynamic library `libCfunc.so`. This library is placed under the path `/home/cuiyujie/workspace/library/lib`.

I added this path to library path `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/cuiyujie/workspace/library/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
When I use the following command to compile, it can be compiled normally.

```
gcc testFunc.c  -lCfunc -lm -O0 -g -o testFunc
```

But when I run it, if I use `./testFunc`, it can run normally.

But if I use `sudo ./testFunc`, he will get the following error.

> ./testFunc: error while loading shared libraries: libCfunc.so: cannot
> open shared object file: No such file or directory

I found on Google that when root is used, the value of the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable is ignored.
I used the following command to recompile. Specify the library path when compiling.

```
gcc testFunc.c  -L/home/cuiyujie/workspace/library/lib -lCfunc -lm -O0 -g -o testFunc
```

When I continue to run with the `sudo ./testFunc` command, the same error still appears.

The reason why I need to execute with root is because I need to read some inquiries that only root privileges can read. I want to get the physical address of certain variables, so I need to read the mapping file of the process, which requires root privileges.

Comment: Why are you compiling as `root` in the first place?

Comment: Compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra testFunc.c  -lCfunc -lm -O -g -o testFunc`, and explain, in several paragraphs of written English, why you need to run your executable as root. Most of the time it is a very bad idea (because of [cyber security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_security) concerns)

Comment: Thanks. But I am running as root and did not compile with root. I added reasons. After compiling with the above method, the error still appears.

Comment: On all the Linux distributions I know about, the pseudo-file `/proc/self/maps` (see [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)...) is readable for a process without root privileges. You don't need to be root. At last, the *physical* address can change at arbitrary moments. If you really care about them, you may need to patch and compile the [Linux kernel](https://kernel.org/). Budget several months of effort for that

Comment: No.  I wrote a separate file to output the physical address corresponding to the virtual address of any process through the command line. And on my server, this file should not be readable without root permissions.

Comment: Please provide some [mre] - that means, a C source with a `main` - in your question. Even a process running as root can have its physical address changing arbitrarily. See also [mlock(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html) and **show some C code in your question**; AFAIK the kernel could move pages at arbitrary moments (between two machine instructions in user land...)

Comment: If the root file is not used, the data in /proc/self/pagemap cannot be read. I tried it on several servers. Without root privileges, the page frame number cannot be read， and the page frame number is always 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linker flag `-L` just tells the linker where to look for the library (or a library stub, if such is used) at link time. It does not influence the library search path at runtime.

For a system wide installed library you'd place the library in a place that's been configured in the global linker search path, set through `/etc/ld.so.conf` and files in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`.

However it is perfectly possible to specify additional search paths specific to certain binaries by means of the so callled *rpath*. The *rpath*  is set using the (you guessed it) `rpath` **extra** linker flag `-Wl,-rpath`.

Linking the program with

```
gcc -o … -Wl,-rpath='${ORIGIN}' …
```

would make the ELF interpreter (the piece of code that loads ELF binaries and does dynamic linkage) to *also* look for additional libraries right next to the program binary. You can read up on the details of rpaths in the `ld.so` manpage.

Be aware that rpaths invoke certain security considerations.

Answer (score 3):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is an environment variable, and all environment variables exist separately for each user.

When you export it under your regular user, but then run the executable as root using `sudo`, the export does not exist for the new process.

You can preserve the environment of your user with the -E parameter:

```
sudo -E ./testFunc
```

or you can specifically preserve the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable like this:

```
sudo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/cuiyujie/workspace/library/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./testFunc
```